# AssertionError: The field '' was declared on serializer '' but has not been included in the 'fields' option. optional

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im, using Django Rest Framework to make an APIRest but I got this error when trying to make a simple crud for the discount resource

This is my model

```
class Discount(BaseModel):
    """ Discount Model. """
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rate = models.DecimalField( max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    class DiscountStatus(models.TextChoices):
        ENABLED = 'ENABLED'
        DISABLED = 'DISABLED'
        REDEEMED = 'REDEEMED'
    status = models.CharField("status", choices=DiscountStatus.choices, default=DiscountStatus.ENABLED,  max_length=10)
    insurance_company = models.ForeignKey("sanitas.InsuranceCompany", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appointment = models.ForeignKey("sanitas.Appointment", verbose_name="appointment", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta():
        """ Meta class. """
        db_table = 'discounts'
```

This is my serializer

```
class DiscountModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Insurance company model serializer. """

    insurance_company = InsuranceCompanyModelSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
    insurance_company_id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, required=False,)

    appointment = AppointmentModelSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
    appointment_id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta():
        """ Meta class. """
        model = Discount
        fields = (
            'id',
            'code',
            'rate',
            'status',
            'appointment'
            'insurance_company'
            'insurance_company_id'
            'appointment_id'
        )
```

And this is my Viewset

```
class DiscountViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ Schedule items will be the time unit to manage appointments. """

    queryset = Discount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DiscountModelSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def generate(self, request):
        """ Create dicounts in bulk. """
        rate = 1 - request.data['rate'] / 100
        insurance_company = get_object_or_404(InsuranceCompany, pk=request.data['insurance_company_id'])
        count = 0
        amount = request.data['amount']
        response = []
        while count < amount:
            code = insurance_company.code + randomString(8)
            discount = Discount()
            discount.rate = rate
            discount.code = code
            discount.insurance_company = insurance_company      
            discount.save()
            serializer = DiscountModelSerializer(discount)
            response.append(serializer.data)
            count = count + 1
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My guess is that the error appears because I have an optional field (is not really optional, but when I create the discount codes there is no appointment yet so it will be added later) and the error appears because I didn't add the field "appointment" and when trying to retrieve the resources I make It shows this error

```
AssertionError at /discounts/generate/ The field 'appointment_id' was declared on serializer DiscountModelSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.
```

Comment: Looks like you missed commas after field names: e.g. it should be `'appointment',`.

Comment: you are missing commas **`,`** after the field name in your serializer.

Comment: holy crap Im dumb.....thanks alot! XD